# Use g++-4.8 with Qt

Tags: compiling, gcc, qt, g++, qmake

I am trying to compile a Qt project that uses the "override" keyword, and thus needs GCC 4.8. I have installed GCC 4.8 on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine already, and it lives in /usr/bin as gcc-4.8 and g++-4.8.

I have added a compiler in the Qt Creator with the "Compiler path" set to `/usr/bin/g++-4.8`, and made sure the kit I am using is set to use this compiler. However, the Makefile that qmake generates still sets `CC = gcc` and `CXX = g++`. If I manually append `-4.8`, it does what I want. Why is qmake not generating the Makefile to do that? What am I missing in Qt Creator such that it points to the wrong gcc binaries?

I realize that `update-alternatives` could do the job, but I'd like to not have to have to run that just to run an alternative version of gcc. (Maybe in the future I will want two Qt projects with different versions of gcc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out how to fix this: add the following to my `.pro` file:

```
linux-g++ | linux-g++-64 | linux-g++-32 {
    QMAKE_CXX = g++-4.8
    QMAKE_CC = gcc-4.8
}
```

Comment: I'm told that `linux-g++*` would work in place of `linux-g++ | linux-g++-64 | linux-g++-32`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a generic fix, but rather a workaround of the apparent limitation that qt creator did not use the proper name of the binary defined for the compiler in the kit... This problem occured in Qt Creator 3.5.1, but I have not tested it in newer releases.